# How to cancel a copy operation in ranger file manager?

Tags: ranger

When I move files and paste in another location, sometimes I make a mistake typing <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> instead <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>. Then I can't find any means to cancel the copy operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. It worked for me. I got it from this discussion: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1211500

Answer (score 14):

Press <kbd>w</kbd> to display all running/queued operations, move (with <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> or arrows) to the desired operation and press <kbd>dd</kbd> to cancel it.